# HTTP Cookie is not set in Request header by Mozilla. This happens when I access web page through ipv6 address. But this issue is not seen in Chrome

Tags: html, cgi, httpcookie

I acesss the web page with address 30.30.30.2: There is a login.cgi file. The web page has set cookie in response header. Then the form is submitted and the data is sent to default.html. For default.html web page has fills the cookie in request header. This behavior is fine.

But when i access the webpage with ipv6 address [2c00::2002] I see that the cookie is set in Response header by web page but browser in turn is not filling cookie in Request header.

Ipv4:

**login.cgi:**

**Response Header:**

Connection: close

Content-Type: text/html

Date: Thu, 01 Jan 2004 00:27:14 GMT

//Cookie set in response header by Web page

**Set-Cookie: FTMSession=6bt5d78e9ba8c91a7fe728de94e86b48f79bW01dd54bee31721c7d374ac077e16bw5d78e9ba8c91a7fe728he94e86b48f79bV01dd54bee31721c7d374ac077e1;domain=30.30.30.2;path=/; secure; httponly**

Status: "200 OK"

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

X-Frame-Options: sameorigin

**default.html:**

**Request header:**

Host: 30.30.30.2

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101

Firefox/44.0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Referer: https://30.30.30.2/protected/login.cgi

//Cookie set in Request header by Web page

**Cookie:
FTMSession=6bt5d78e9ba8c91a7fe728de94e86b48f79bW01dd54bee31721c7d374ac077e16bw5d78e9ba8c91a7fe728he94e86b48f79bV01dd54bee31721c7d374ac077e1**

Connection: keep-alive

This is fine. But for ipv6 the coookie is set by Web page but in turn not set by Browser in Request header